# Created an interface To get Arraylist but still getting null

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask

In my app i wanna use the ArrayList from the async Class in other class.So for that i have created an interface.But when i am using that interface in other class i am getting the size of ArrayList as 0.The arraylist i am using in other class is give it to the custom adapter for displayn the List.But as my Arraylist size is 0, blank list is being displayed

Async Class

```
public class SearchJobAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements GetArrayList {
    private String response;
    Context c;
    SearchModel data;
    ArrayList<SearchModel> values;
    GetArrayList getArrayList;

    public SearchJobAsync(Context c, GetArrayList getArrayList) {
        this.c = c;
        this.getArrayList = getArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute ();
        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "Please Wait...", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        values = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();

        super.onPostExecute (s);
        if (!s.trim ().contains ("Table")) {
            Crouton.makeText ((android.app.Activity) c, "Nothing found", Style.INFO).show ();
        } else {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                JSONObject NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                    data = new SearchModel (table.getString ("Job_Category"), table.getString ("Min_Exp"), table.getString ("Max_Exp"), table.getString ("Posted_On"), table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"), table.getString ("Applications"), table.getString ("No_Of_Pos"), table.getString ("Job_Desc"), table.getString ("Job_Type"), table.getString ("Job_Hours"), table.getString ("Job_Status"), table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date"), table.getString ("Address"), table.getString ("Gender_Name"), table.getString ("Religion_Name"), table.getString ("Exp_Summary"), table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID"), table.getString ("Requestor_Name"));
                    values.add (data);
                    if(values.size()>0){
                        getArrayList.getList(values);
                    }
                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");

                    for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject (i);
                        data = new SearchModel (table.getString ("Job_Category"), table.getString ("Min_Exp"), table.getString ("Max_Exp"), table.getString ("Posted_On"), table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"), table.getString ("Applications"), table.getString ("No_Of_Pos"), table.getString ("Job_Desc"), table.getString ("Job_Type"), table.getString ("Job_Hours"), table.getString ("Job_Status"), table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date"), table.getString ("Address"), table.getString ("Gender_Name"), table.getString ("Religion_Name"), table.getString ("Exp_Summary"), table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID"), table.getString ("Requestor_Name"));
                        values.add (data);
                        if(values.size()>0){
                            getArrayList.getList(values);
                        }

                    }

                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
        }


        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "", false);
        Intent i = new Intent (c, SearchJobListActivity.class);
        c.startActivity (i);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... s) {
        response = HttpRequest.post ("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/FindJobForVendor").send ("Vendor_IEntity_Code=" + "34588A34-E969-4723-84FE-E5409B66A5B7" + "&Job_Code=" + "&Job_Category=1" + "&Exp_Years_From=0" + "&Exp_Months_From=0" + "&Exp_Years_To=0" + "&Exp_Months_To=0").body ();
        response = response.replaceAll ("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll ("\n", "");
        Log.e ("Search Jobs", "" + response);
        return response;
    }


    @Override
    public void getList(ArrayList<SearchModel> data) {
       values=data;
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface GetArrayList  {

public void getList(ArrayList<SearchModel> data);
}
```

Class where i am using the ArrayList

```
public class SearchJobList extends ListFragment implements GetArrayList {
    private View view;
    private ListView lvSearchJobs;
    private ArrayList<SearchModel> value;
    SearchJobCustomList customList;
    SearchJobAsync searchJobAsync;
    private Context c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.search_job_lists, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
        c = getActivity ();
        lvSearchJobs = (ListView) getActivity ().findViewById (android.R.id.list);
        value = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();
        searchJobAsync = new SearchJobAsync (c,this);
        customList = new SearchJobCustomList (c, value);
        setListAdapter (customList);
//        searchJobAsync.execute ();


    }

    @Override
    public void getList(ArrayList<SearchModel> data) {
        value=data;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you start SearchJobListActivity in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: @Haresh then where shud i start???

Comment: What you are trying to do is on your SearchJobList fragment execute SearchJobAsync and when data come from response try to show result on your SearchJobList fragment is it or anything else ?

Comment: Yes u r right ,but for the data to be displayed on the list i want the ArrayList from Async Class

Comment: dont start SearchJobListActivity in onPostExecute() use onItemClickListener for listview and initialize your adapter at  setListAdapter (customList); on onPostExecute()...

Comment: @santhosh sorry dint get u sir??

Comment: Actually at what situation you want to start the SearchJobListActivity as of your requirement.

Comment: I wanna start when the user clicks on the search Button the async Class gets all the json data and parse it and after parsing i wanna display the data in the list

Answer (score 0):

You probably should define your interface like this:

```
public interface GetArrayList  {    
  List<SearchModel> getList();
}
```

then you can return a list object like this:

```
@Override
public List<SearchModel> getList() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(value);
}
```

Your current interface is quite odd, but it could be made to work if your implementation of it was sound. Currently, your `getList()` implementation is acting like a setter and not a getter. You could do something like:

```
@Override
public void getList(ArrayList<SearchModel> data) {
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(value);
}
```

Final note: `GetArrayList` is a strange name for an interface. Normally interfaces should be named in a descriptive way, not directly after the methods they hold. For instance, you might call your interface `ListHolder` or `SearchModelCatalogue`.

Comment: @Anuj Simply `values = getArrayList.getList();`.

Comment: sir i did what u said but i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: @Anuj Hard to advise without seeing your adjusted code. Any chance that `SearchJobList.getList()` is being called before `SearchJobList.onActivityCreated()`? If that happens, your list is null.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class SearchJobList extends ListFragment {
    private View view;
    private ListView lvSearchJobs;
    private ArrayList<SearchModel> value;
    SearchJobCustomList customList;
    SearchJobAsync searchJobAsync;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.search_job_lists, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
        lvSearchJobs = (ListView) getActivity ().findViewById (android.R.id.list);
        new SearchJobAsync(getActivity(),new GetArrayList() {
            @Override
            public void getList(ArrayList<SearchModel> data) {
                value = data;
                customList = new SearchJobCustomList (c, value);
                setListAdapter (customList);
            }
        }).execute();
    }

}

public class SearchJobAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context c;
    private String response;
    SearchModel data;
    ArrayList<SearchModel> values;
    GetArrayList getArrayList;

    public SearchJobAsync(Context c, GetArrayList getArrayList) {
        this.c = c;
        this.getArrayList = getArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute ();
        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "Please Wait...", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        values = new ArrayList<SearchModel> ();

        super.onPostExecute (s);
        if (!s.trim ().contains ("Table")) {
            Crouton.makeText ((android.app.Activity) c, "Nothing found", Style.INFO).show ();
        } else {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                JSONObject NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                    data = new SearchModel (table.getString ("Job_Category"), table.getString ("Min_Exp"), table.getString ("Max_Exp"), table.getString ("Posted_On"), table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"), table.getString ("Applications"), table.getString ("No_Of_Pos"), table.getString ("Job_Desc"), table.getString ("Job_Type"), table.getString ("Job_Hours"), table.getString ("Job_Status"), table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date"), table.getString ("Address"), table.getString ("Gender_Name"), table.getString ("Religion_Name"), table.getString ("Exp_Summary"), table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID"), table.getString ("Requestor_Name"));
                    values.add (data);
                } else if (NewDataSet.get ("Table") instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray tableArray = NewDataSet.getJSONArray ("Table");

                    for (int i = 0; i < tableArray.length (); i++) {
                        JSONObject table = tableArray.getJSONObject (i);
                        data = new SearchModel (table.getString ("Job_Category"), table.getString ("Min_Exp"), table.getString ("Max_Exp"), table.getString ("Posted_On"), table.getString ("Candidate_Counts"), table.getString ("Applications"), table.getString ("No_Of_Pos"), table.getString ("Job_Desc"), table.getString ("Job_Type"), table.getString ("Job_Hours"), table.getString ("Job_Status"), table.getString ("Job_Exp_Date"), table.getString ("Address"), table.getString ("Gender_Name"), table.getString ("Religion_Name"), table.getString ("Exp_Summary"), table.getString ("IJob_Request_ID"), table.getString ("Requestor_Name"));
                        values.add (data);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
            CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "Please Wait...",false);
            getArrayList.getList(values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... s) {
        response = HttpRequest.post ("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/FindJobForVendor").send ("Vendor_IEntity_Code=" + "34588A34-E969-4723-84FE-E5409B66A5B7" + "&Job_Code=" + "&Job_Category=1" + "&Exp_Years_From=0" + "&Exp_Months_From=0" + "&Exp_Years_To=0" + "&Exp_Months_To=0").body ();
        response = response.replaceAll ("<[^>]*>", "").replaceAll ("\n", "");
        Log.e ("Search Jobs", "" + response);
        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: i did what u said but i am nt going to the ListActivity,it remains on the same page